# How to move a car over an environment

Tags: collision-detection, movement

At the moment I'm writing a little OpenGL application. For now I have a car which can drive down a road. This works really good because I simply put the car on the street plane. Now let's say on the road is a little ramp and my car should be able to drive along that ramp. How can I do this? At the moment I only have translation along the z axis. Let me describe how I would do it:

- Calculate angle between ramp and street normal
- Rotate car by this angle and translate it

First of all: Is there an easier way to do it? My main problem from this idea is how should I get the normal from the triangle the car is interacting with? And of course I can not rotate the car the full angle at the beginning because then a part of the car is under the ground. So what is the usual way to do this?

Comment: OpenGL is purely an API to allow you to write graphics to an output and cannot achieve what you want. You need to look into physics and collisions, for example [Bullet Physics](bulletphysics.org) is library that can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no usual way. It all depends on how precise you want your simulation to be.

A very cheap way:

[image]

You can improve on this by using it as a **starting point** and then adjusting the position more realistically.

To rotate the vehicle as it moves have each wheel rotate the car by using its opposite wheel as the pivot point.

[image]

If it becomes too problematic due to corner cases you should look into using a ready-made physics system. Proper physics are a big headache.

It does not remove the need for the solution above as you will need to properly position vehicles initially before the physics system takes over if you don't want cars to spawn in the air or partially **into** the ground and fly off when the physics system freaks out.

Answer (score 3):

Just about the easiest way to do this is to calculate the cars position from the road, and it's rotation with the normal of the road, like you mentioned yourself. This will cause your car to stick to the road even if you create an abrupt fall in the road however.

To solve jumps on the road you either have to simulate falling yourself by keeping track of the last height the car had and if the new height is less than that, start applying gravity to a fall speed and ignore the roads angle until the car lands again.

Or you could look into using a physics engine like [bullet physics](http://bulletphysics.org/), it's a bit more complex and sounds like overkill for your scenario, but if your planning on adding obstacles, other cars and perhaps simulate losing traction, then it might be the easiest option in the long run.

Comment: Okay thank you for that but my main problem is how do I know on which triangle is car is? I have to know this because I have to calculate the rotation with the normal of the current "ground" triangle. So how can I get it?